# How to delete synced photos from an iPad?

Tags: ipad, photos

How can I delete photos from photos on my iPad.  They were copied when I did a sync with the computer. I'm talking about 1650 photos and I don't want all of them.

Comment: Are you talking about photos in the Photostream or just regulars on your iPad?

Comment: Photos synced to an iDevice from a computer do not enter the Photostream, only photos taken on the device and saved to the camera roll will automatically push to the cloud.  @Michiel

Comment: He's asking to delete photos of his iPad, no?

Comment: Will you dix the question title to: "How to delete synced photos from an iPad?"

Answer (score 3):

Sync again with the computer, this time when it is plugged in, click on the iPad, and navigate to syncing options, and Photos, uncheck, Sync Photos. Then sync

Comment: thanks for your reply...I am new...how do i navigate to sync options where I can uncheck?

Comment: the downloaded pictures got deleted..all of them. I unchecked the folder on the pc before I did the sync. How can I transfer selected photos from my pc to my iPad? Do i create a folder with those pictures on the pc , select it, then sync?

Comment: @Shauket That will work.